# How to convert Mysql table contents to json using webapi?

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, json

```
 public class theatresController : ApiController
   {
    [HttpGet]
   public static DataTable GetAlltheatredet()
     {
       try
         {
      string connString = "Server=localhost;database=mytable;uid=root;";
      string query = "SELECT TheatreName FROM `mytable`.`theatredetails`";
      MySqlDataAdapter ma = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, connString);
      DataSet DS = new DataSet();
      ma.Fill(DS);
      return DS.Tables[0];
         }
catch (MySqlException e)
        {
            throw new Exception(e.Message);
        }
      }
```

I am fetching my table data from DB by using datatable. How can I convert all these datas to json

I tried by using this in an html file

```
$(document).ready(function ()
    {
      $("#Theaterdet").click(function ()
        {
            alert("in document submit");
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/api/theatres/",
                dataType: 'json',
success: function (data) 
                {

                },
                error: function () 
                {
                    alert("Error while invoking the Web API");
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

But I got error... How can I implement this functionality?

Comment: i have been using this method   `public Stream ConvertDataSetToJson(DataSet ds)
        {
            try
            {


                byte[] resultBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ds, Formatting.Indented));
                WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "text/plain";
                return new MemoryStream(resultBytes);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }`

Comment: [Please don't return a DataTable from a web service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25874224/why-returning-dataset-or-data-table-from-wcf-service-is-not-a-good-practice-wha). Use an ORM and/or return a DTO. If you don't want that and want help with your current approach, at least share the error you get.

Comment: @CodeCaster:Error while invoking the Web API.The control can't go to the apicontroller

Comment: The `error` function of an `$.ajax()` request has parameters. Using those you can obtain the actual error.

Comment: @CodeCaster:what i need to write in success function?